# create id variable from table of duplicates

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where each row has a unique identifier, but some rows are actually duplicates.

```r
fdf <- data.frame(name = c("fred", "ferd", "frad", 'eric', "eirc", "george"),
                  id = 1:6)
fdf
#>     name id
#> 1   fred  1
#> 2   ferd  2
#> 3   frad  3
#> 4   eric  4
#> 5   eirc  5
#> 6 george  6
```

I have determined which rows are duplicated and this information is stored in a second dataframe as pairs of the unique id's. So the key tells me row 1 is the same individual as rows 2 and 3, etc.

```r
key <- data.frame(id1 = c(1,1,2,4), id2 = c(2,3,3,5))
key
#>   id1 id2
#> 1   1   2
#> 2   1   3
#> 3   2   3
#> 4   4   5
```

I'm struggling to think up a straightforward way to use the key to create an id variable in my original dataframe. Desired output would be:

```r
fdf$realid <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
fdf
#>     name id realid
#> 1   fred  1      1
#> 2   ferd  2      1
#> 3   frad  3      1
#> 4   eric  4      2
#> 5   eirc  5      2
#> 6 george  6      3
```

#### Edit for clarity

Keys here are the set of true connections between rows in the data.frame `fdf`. Thus you can imagine starting with the set of all feasible connections:

```r
#  id1 id2
#   1   2
#   1   3
#   1   4
#   ...
#   6   4
#   6   5
```

determining which are true connections (based on the other variables in each observation).

```r
#  id1 id2 match
#   1   2   match
#   1   3  no match
#   1   4   match
#   ...
#   6   4   no match
#   6   5   no match
```

and sub-setting to the cases that are matches.

Comment: Are the names actually the same in the data?

Comment: no this is just a toy example. real data has more variables, including long strings with spelling errors.

Comment: Can you explain your keypairs more in detail? E.g. how does 1 eqals 2, 1 equals 3 and 2 equals 3 add up?

Comment: key pairs are connections between rows in the `fdf` data.frame. since the first three observations (id = 1 though 3) of `fdf` are duplicated, the key says 1 is linked to 2, 1 is linked to 3, and of course 2 is linked to 3. 2 has to be equal to 3 if 1 is equal to 2 and 3 because "equal" is transitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a 'straight forward way', but it seems to work well.

First you check which IDs are together in a group, by checking whether there's 'overlap', i.e. whether the intersection between two rows in `key` is non-empty:

```
check_overlap <- function(pair1, pair2){
  newset <- intersect(pair1, pair2)
  length(newset) != 0
}
```

Then we can apply this function to the rows in `key` against the other rows. If a row has been matched already, it is automatically removed from `key`, like this:

```
check_overlaps <- function(key){
  cont <- data.frame()
  i <- 1
  while(nrow(key) > 0){
    ids  <- apply(key, 1, check_overlap, key[1, ])
    vals <- unique(unlist(key[ids, ]))
    key  <- key[!ids, ]
    cont <- rbind(cont, cbind(vals, rep(i, length(vals))))
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(cont)
}

new_ids <- check_overlaps(key)
#    vals V2
# 1    1  1
# 2    2  1
# 3    3  1
# 4    4  2
# 5    5  2
```

The problem with merging `fdf` and `new_ids`, however, is that some old IDs may not occur in `key`, but they should be mapped to a new ID according to the new order. You can manipulate `key` a bit a priori and do:

```
for(val in unique(fdf$id)){
  if(!(val %in% unlist(key))){
    key <- rbind(key, c(val, val))
  }
}

new_ids2 <- check_overlaps(key)
     vals V2
# 1    1  1
# 2    2  1
# 3    3  1
# 4    4  2
# 5    5  2
# 6    6  3
```

Which is easy to merge with `fdf` like:

```
merge(fdf, new_ids2, by.x = "id", by.y = "vals")
    id   name V2
# 1  1   fred  1
# 2  2   ferd  1
# 3  3   frad  1
# 4  4   eric  2
# 5  5   eirc  2
# 6  6 george  3
```

Comment: This does what I asked so I've accepted your answer. Ultimately it was too slow however given the size of my data so i found a faster solution using igraph (following a suggestion above): `g <- graph_from_data_frame(key, directed=FALSE); new_ids <- components(g)$membership` gets me there.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to recreate the *key* data frame to the following format (i.e. which id belongs to which realid)

```
key <- data.frame(id     = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                  realid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3))
```

Then it is just a matter of merging *fdf* and *key* together with *merge*

```
fdf <- merge(fdf, key_table, by.x = "id")
fdf
  id   name realid
1  1   fred      1
2  2   ferd      1
3  3   frad      1
4  4   eric      2
5  5   eirc      2
6  6 george      3
```

Comment: If OP needs help generating this `key` from their `key` - the problem is equivalent to a graph theory problem. If we think of their key as a list of edges in a graph, this answer's key is assigning a `realid` to each clique. The `igraph` package can help to find all the cliques.

Comment: yes @Gregor this is exactly the problem. this answer is not workable for me because I have 10's of thousands of matches.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it can be solved by creating groups of matching ids and creating a new (real) id out of these groups:

```
# determine the groups of ids
id_groups <- list()
i = 1
for (id in unique(key$id1)) {
  if (!(id %in% unlist(id_groups))) {
    id_groups[[i]] <- c(id, key$id2[key$id1 == id])
    i = i + 1
  }
}

# add ids without match
id_groups <- c(id_groups, setdiff(fdf$id, unlist(id_groups)))

# for every id in fdf, set real_id to index in id_groups to which id belongs
fdf$real_id <- sapply(fdf$id, function(id) {
  which(sapply(id_groups, function(group) id %in% group))
})
```